# Display Chrome extension popup at middle of page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to writing chrome extensions and was wondering how can i do the following.

How can i make the popup(when someone clicks on extension icon) display at the center of the webpage instead of displaying the popup at the top right corner ?

Answer (score 1):

Use chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(), which [fires "when a browser action icon is clicked."](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked) Then inject your popup manually into the DOM of the supplied tab, using something like chrome.tabs.executeScript().

Also consider adding a [context-menu item](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html), which might make more sense to a user depending on what your extension actually does.